# Center horizontally with only one View for constraint

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Is there a way, using `ConstraintLayout` to achieve the below, without setting an invisible View on the right side as well? (The right back arrow should be invisible, I've made it visible to make things easier to understand)

[image]

The middle view currently is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/cover_wrapper"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:onClick="@{(view) -> viewModel.onAutoPlayButtonClick()}"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/back_button"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/dummy_button"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/buttons_wrapper"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="3:4">
```

Besides simply setting a right margin calculated as `button_width + button_margin_left + button_margin_right`, is there a trick to not have the right View there and not use margins either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can achieve that using `ConstraintLayout` and `Guidelines` without setting any invisible View

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tint="@color/green"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="?attr/actionModeCloseDrawable" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView"
        />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".3" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".7" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah, i thought of that, but I'd still like the left margin of back button and spacing between back button and the middle View to be constant. But not a bad solution ...

Comment: you can make it constant